# Attaching parameters to subprocess.call()

Tags: python, linux, raspberry-pi, debian, raspbian

I am trying to run commands via Python on my Raspberry Pi using Raspbian with the subprocess.call command. Specifically, I'm trying to use it to take a photo with the camera which, just for the record, works fine as I can use raspistill and achieve the desired output.

Here's my python code:

```
#PROCEDURE TO TAKE PHOTO WITH DEFAULT CAMERA ON RASPBERRY PI
import subprocess
def pyraspistill(name):
    subprocess.call(['/usr/bin/raspistill','-o',name + ".jpg"], shell=True)
pyraspistill("name")
```

However, instead of taking the photo with the given parameters, it justs lists me info about the raspistill command. Why? How do I avoid this?

For reference, here's what it returns (and no it isn't also giving an image):

```
george@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo python camera.py

raspistill Camera App v1.3.11

Runs camera for specific time, and take JPG capture at end if requested

usage: raspistill [options]

Image parameter commands

-?, --help      : This help information
-w, --width     : Set image width <size>
-h, --height    : Set image height <size>
-q, --quality   : Set jpeg quality <0 to 100>
-r, --raw       : Add raw bayer data to jpeg metadata
-o, --output    : Output filename <filename> (to write to stdout, use '-o -'). If not specified, no file is saved
-l, --latest    : Link latest complete image to filename <filename>
-v, --verbose   : Output verbose information during run
-t, --timeout   : Time (in ms) before takes picture and shuts down (if not specified, set to 5s)
-th, --thumb    : Set thumbnail parameters (x:y:quality) or none
-d, --demo      : Run a demo mode (cycle through range of camera options, no capture)
-e, --encoding  : Encoding to use for output file (jpg, bmp, gif, png)
-x, --exif      : EXIF tag to apply to captures (format as 'key=value') or none
-tl, --timelapse        : Timelapse mode. Takes a picture every <t>ms. %d == frame number (Try: -o img_%04d.jpg)
-fp, --fullpreview      : Run the preview using the still capture resolution (may reduce preview fps)
-k, --keypress  : Wait between captures for a ENTER, X then ENTER to exit
-s, --signal    : Wait between captures for a SIGUSR1 or SIGUSR2 from another process
-g, --gl        : Draw preview to texture instead of using video render component
-gc, --glcapture        : Capture the GL frame-buffer instead of the camera image
-set, --settings        : Retrieve camera settings and write to stdout
-cs, --camselect        : Select camera <number>. Default 0
-bm, --burst    : Enable 'burst capture mode'
-md, --mode     : Force sensor mode. 0=auto. See docs for other modes available
-dt, --datetime : Replace output pattern (%d) with DateTime (MonthDayHourMinSec)
-ts, --timestamp        : Replace output pattern (%d) with unix timestamp (seconds since 1970)
-fs, --framestart       : Starting frame number in output pattern(%d)
-rs, --restart  : JPEG Restart interval (default of 0 for none)
-gps, --gpsdexif        : Apply real-time GPS information from gpsd as EXIF tags (requires libgps.so.22)

Preview parameter commands

-p, --preview   : Preview window settings <'x,y,w,h'>
-f, --fullscreen        : Fullscreen preview mode
-op, --opacity  : Preview window opacity (0-255)
-n, --nopreview : Do not display a preview window

Image parameter commands

-sh, --sharpness        : Set image sharpness (-100 to 100)
-co, --contrast : Set image contrast (-100 to 100)
-br, --brightness       : Set image brightness (0 to 100)
-sa, --saturation       : Set image saturation (-100 to 100)
-ISO, --ISO     : Set capture ISO
-vs, --vstab    : Turn on video stabilisation
-ev, --ev       : Set EV compensation - steps of 1/6 stop
-ex, --exposure : Set exposure mode (see Notes)
-fli, --flicker : Set flicker avoid mode (see Notes)
-awb, --awb     : Set AWB mode (see Notes)
-ifx, --imxfx   : Set image effect (see Notes)
-cfx, --colfx   : Set colour effect (U:V)
-mm, --metering : Set metering mode (see Notes)
-rot, --rotation        : Set image rotation (0-359)
-hf, --hflip    : Set horizontal flip
-vf, --vflip    : Set vertical flip
-roi, --roi     : Set region of interest (x,y,w,d as normalised coordinates [0.0-1.0])
-ss, --shutter  : Set shutter speed in microseconds
-awbg, --awbgains       : Set AWB gains - AWB mode must be off
-drc, --drc     : Set DRC Level (see Notes)
-st, --stats    : Force recomputation of statistics on stills capture pass
-a, --annotate  : Enable/Set annotate flags or text
-3d, --stereo   : Select stereoscopic mode
-dec, --decimate        : Half width/height of stereo image
-3dswap, --3dswap       : Swap camera order for stereoscopic
-ae, --annotateex       : Set extra annotation parameters (text size, text colour(hex YUV), bg colour(hex YUV), justify, x, y)
-ag, --analoggain       : Set the analog gain (floating point)
-dg, --digitalgain      : Set the digital gain (floating point)


Notes

Exposure mode options :
off,auto,night,nightpreview,backlight,spotlight,sports,snow,beach,verylong,fixedfps,antishake,fireworks

Flicker avoid mode options :
off,auto,50hz,60hz

AWB mode options :
off,auto,sun,cloud,shade,tungsten,fluorescent,incandescent,flash,horizon

Image Effect mode options :
none,negative,solarise,sketch,denoise,emboss,oilpaint,hatch,gpen,pastel,watercolour,film,blur,saturation,colourswap,washedout,posterise,colourpoint,colourbalance,cartoon

Metering Mode options :
average,spot,backlit,matrix

Dynamic Range Compression (DRC) options :
off,low,med,high

Preview parameter commands

-gs, --glscene  : GL scene square,teapot,mirror,yuv,sobel,vcsm_square
-gw, --glwin    : GL window settings <'x,y,w,h'>
enter code here
```

Comment: Do not use `shell=True`, because only the *first* item will get passed to the command, the other arguments *get passed as arguments to the shell*

Answer (score 1):

Answer:

Do not use shell=True, because only the first item will get passed to the command, the other arguments get passed as arguments to the shell - @juanpa.arrivillaga

Thank you very much. I'm adding this as the answer to conclude question because it was a comment :)